# Why does `echo -e "\\\SOME_TEXT"` show only one backslash?

Tags: linux, bash, echo, escape-characters, escaping

Could some one explain what is happening behind the scenes in character escaping in Linux shell? I tried the following and googled a lot, without any success in understanding what (and how) is going on:

```
root@sv01:~# echo -e "\ Hello!"
\ Hello!
root@sv01:~# echo -e "\\ Hello!"
\ Hello!
root@sv01:~# echo -e "\\\ Hello!"
\ Hello!
root@sv01:~# echo -e "\\\\ Hello!"
\ Hello!
root@sv01:~# echo -e "\\\\\ Hello!"
\\ Hello!
root@sv01:~# echo -e "\\\\\\ Hello!"
\\ Hello!
root@sv01:~# echo -e "\\\\\\\ Hello!"
\\ Hello!
root@sv01:~# echo -e "\\\\\\\\ Hello!"
\\ Hello!
root@sv01:~# echo -e "\\\\\\\\\ Hello!"
\\\ Hello!
root@sv01:~# echo -e "\n Hello!"

 Hello!
root@sv01:~# echo -e "\\n Hello!"

 Hello!
root@sv01:~# echo -e "\\\n Hello!"
\n Hello!
```

I am totally lost there, so for example, why do three backslashes give only one back slash? **I would expect: the first two will be escaped to one, the third one will find nothing to escape so it will remain a slash (line in the first experiment), but what is happening is that the third one is just disappears.**
Why I am getting one backslash from four `\\\\ Hello`? **I would expect each pair will give one back slash -> two backslashes.**

And why I need three backslashes in the last case to get \n escaped? what is happening in background of escaping to get that? and how is it different from `\\n` case?

I appreciate any explanation of what is going on in the previous lines.

Comment: `echo -e` behavior is not standards-defined anyhow -- see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html. Output is *completely implementation-defined* if there's a literal backslash anywhere in the inputs, and the only allowed option is `-n` (meaning that a standards-compliant implementation will have `echo -e` print `-e` on its output).

Comment: ...even if you're 100% sure that your shell is bash, *even then* `echo -e` isn't safe: `echo` will behave in accordance with the standard if both `posix` and `xpg_echo` runtime options are enabled, or if compiled with equivalent build-time options. The safe practice is to use `printf` instead -- see the APPLICATION USAGE and RATIONALE sections of the above link describing how to make `printf` act as a replacement for `echo`.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is because `bash` and `echo -e` combined. From [`man 1 bash`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash)

> A non-quoted backslash (`\`) is the escape character. It preserves the literal value of the next character that follows, with the exception of `<newline>`. […]
>
> Enclosing characters in double quotes preserves the literal value of all characters within the quotes, with the exception of `$`, `` ` ``, `\`, […] The backslash retains its special meaning only when followed by one of the following characters: `$`, `` ` ``, `"`, `\`, or `<newline>`.

The point is: double quoted backslash is not always special.

There are various implementations of `echo` in general, it's a builtin in `bash`; the important thing here is this behavior:

> If `-e` is in effect, the following sequences are recognized:
> `\\`
> backslash
> […]
> `\n`
> new line

Now we can decode:

1. `echo -e "\ Hello!"` – nothing special to `bash`, nothing special to `echo`; `\` stays.
2. `echo -e "\\ Hello!"` – the first `\` tells `bash` to treat the second `\` literally; `echo` gets `\ Hello!` and acts as above.
3. `echo -e "\\\ Hello!"` – the first `\` tells `bash` to treat the second `\` literally; `echo` gets `\\ Hello!` and (because of `-e`) it recognizes `\\` as `\`.
4. `echo -e "\\\\ Hello!"` – the first `\` tells `bash` to treat the second `\` literally; the third tells the same about the fourth; `echo` gets `\\ Hello!` and (because of `-e`) it recognizes `\\` as `\`.
5. `echo -e "\\\\\ Hello!"` – the first `\` tells `bash` to treat the second `\` literally; the third tells the same about the fourth; the last one is not special; `echo` gets `\\\ Hello!` and (because of `-e`) it recognizes the initial `\\` as `\`, the last `\` stays intact.

And so on. As you can see, up to four consecutive backslashes give one in result. That's why you need (at least) nine of them to get three. 9=4+4+1.

Now with `\n`:

1. `echo -e "\n Hello!"` – there's nothing special to `bash`, echo gets the same string and (because of `-e`) it interprets `\n` as a newline.
2. `echo -e "\\n Hello!"` – `bash` interprets `\\` as `\`; `echo` gets `\n Hello!` and the result is the same as above.
3. `echo -e "\\\n Hello!"` – `bash` interprets the initial `\\` as `\`; `echo` gets `\\n Hello!` and (because of `-e`) it interprets `\\` as a literal `\` which needs to be printed.

The results would be different with `'` instead of `"` (due to different `bash` behavior) or without `-e` (different `echo` behavior).

Comment: Thank you very much! So there are two escaping steps, the step done by bash, and the second one by `-e` judges the text already judged by bash, is that right? if that is correct, that removes the confusion. Could you maybe mention how does `sed` behaves? does it has its own build in escape technique? so I mean does it behave like echo with `-e`?

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin Yes, there are two steps. Your original question is fine as it is, let's not make it overcomplicated with `sed`. You may ask another question though (about `sed` only), just do your own research first.

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin `sed` will follow the same basic principles: bash will interpret the command line according to its rules, parsing (and maybe removing) quotes and escapes. The result of that gets passed to `sed`, which interprets it according to *its* escaping rules. BTW, you can simplify this by using a single-quoted string in `bash`, since that doesn't have eny escape interpretation done (by bash) -- bash removes the single-quotes, and passes what's inside them directly to the command.

Comment: I still have a small problem in `echo -e "\\\n Hello!"` case. Here bash will do escaping, and it will become `\\n`, then `-e` will escape the resulted two backslashes `\\n` and then they will become `\n`. now who interprets `\n` to make it new line? Normally in case of `echo -e "\n Hello!"`, bash does nothing, and `-e` interprets `\n` as new line. but in the first mentioned situation interpretation process was done before getting `\n` to get interpreted. Could you explain that please?

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin "Who interprets `\n` to make it new line?" -- no program does. Your last example in the question shows clearly that in this case `\n` is printed, not interpreted.

Comment: Ok my fault, I have been reading about that for 2 days with their nights, therefore apparently I started to mix the cases, I believe I got something else in `sed` which confused me last night (maybe I did something wrong yesterday), but now I tried again the same with `echo -e` and `sed`, and I got the same thing as excepted, thanks!

Comment: May I ask you to take a look at this? this is what made the main confusion, now I understand every detail you wrote (I think), but I still cannot explain what is going on here:
https://superuser.com/questions/1249497/sed-needs-n-to-append-new-line

Comment: @GordonDavisson, that principle is actually pretty well applicable on `sed substitution` but not `appending` and I do not understand why. You may check that in the link above.

Comment: (Aside: Please don't use backtick-style quoting to escape technical terms -- they're for *code*, not English prose that describes code).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski, that was re: prior comment (code-formatting `sed substitution` and `appending` despite neither of those being code), not your answer.