# How do I grep all \\

Tags: grep

What's the command to grep all lines in subdirectories with `\\` (together)? I tried `grep -r "\\\\" .` but that also catches single `\` and I don't know why it would.

Comment: Related: [*Why does `echo -e "\\\SOME_TEXT"` show only one backslash?*](https://superuser.com/q/1249828/432690)

Comment: Grep has the `-F` option for fixed strings (there is a wrapper too `fgrep`) `grep -F '\\'` could work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put single quotes around the four backslashes so that bash doesn’t eat two of them.

Comment: OHHHH Bash is doing it. Derp