# sed, passing capturing group value to subcommand

Tags: bash, sed

Consider following example:

```
echo abc=123 | sed "s/\([^=]*\)=\(.*\)/\1=\2/"
```

outputs

```
abc=123
```

ie. the same as input. We matched everything up until symbol `=` as capturing group 1, and everythying after symbol `=` as capturing group 2. This is just to explain the example.

I can invoke subcommand from sed like this:

```
echo abc=123 | sed "s/\([^=]*\)=\(.*\)/\1=$(date)/"
```

producing:

```
abc=Tue Nov 17 08:35:13 PM CET 2020
```

so I can call zero-arity function to get replacement.

Question: What if I'd like to take capturing group content and call some command on it to get actual replacement? Say:

```
echo abc=123 | sed "s/\([^=]*\)=\(.*\)/\1=$('\2 * 2' | bc)/"
```

producing:

```
bash: \2 * 2: command not found
abc=123
```

What I need to capture some text, and run some command on it to get replacement. How to do that?

Comment: you are correct, when creating minimal example I dropped `.*` in pattern, will update. Thanks.

Comment: I tried to read into example of GNU sed, which I could work with, and saw some oversimplistic exapmles, but I have no idea how to make it work even in this simple example. If you know how to write that, I'd be grateful to learn that.

Answer (score 0):

`$(date)` does not "invoke subcommand from `sed`". The shell expands double-quoted `$(…)` before `sed` is run. The output from `date` appears in the command and this is what `sed` *gets*. Your command

> ```
> echo abc=123 | sed "s/\([^=]*\)=\(.*\)/\1=$(date)/"
> ```

became this:

```
echo abc=123 | sed "s/\([^=]*\)=\(.*\)/\1=Tue Nov 17 08:35:13 PM CET 2020/"
```

and only then `sed` started. With this approach you cannot pass anything from `sed` itself to `date` (or `bc`, or whatever) because the inside of `$(…)` finishes before `sed` starts.

Standard `sed` cannot do what you want. [GNU `sed` can](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/194229/108618) thanks to the `e` flag. Let's build an example with GNU `sed` and `bc`.

```
echo abc=123 | sed "s/\([^=]*\)=\(.*\)/printf '%s' '\1='; printf '%s\n' '\2 * 2' | bc/e"
#                                      ----------------------------------------------
```

Without `e` the underlined fragment would be a replacement. With `e` it gets *executed* in a shell and its output becomes the replacement.

`\n` is there because in my tests `bc` didn't work with incomplete lines. Note this `\n` is interpreted by `sed` itself, `printf` will get an actual newline character. A point when `printf` gets `\n` to interpret is with `%s\\\\n`. This is because your current shell changes `\\\\n` in a double-quoted string to `\\n`, `sed` interprets `\\` as `\`, the inner shell gets single-quoted `\n` and only then `printf` gets `\n` (more levels than in [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1249828/432690), but similar). Having `\n` interpreted by `sed` does not break the command so you can stick to this simple form.

It would be nice if you could leave the `abc=` part intact and only replace `123`. For this a lookbehind feature is useful, but [`sed` does not support it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26110266/10765659). [One of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26110465/10765659) to the linked question advises a capture group and a backreference in the replacement string, this is exactly what we did with `\1`.

---

One big problem with running a shell command this way is there's a code injection vulnerability. In the shell-command-to-be we single-quoted `\1` and `\2`. If `sed` substitutes any of them with a string containing `'` the inner shell will close the quoting prematurely. Try the following command (the `sed` part is the same as above):

```
echo "abc=123'; rm -i /very/important/file'" \
 | sed "s/\([^=]*\)=\(.*\)/printf '%s' '\1='; printf '%s\n' '\2 * 2' | bc/e"
```

(I used `rm -i` in case you really have `/very/important/file` in your system.)

You need to be sure the input won't inject code. Or you need to rewrite the regex (`[^=]*` and `.*` parts) so possibly dangerous `'` cannot get from arbitrary input to the shell command. Note if we single-quoted the entire `sed` expression and double-quoted `\1` and `\2`, the double-quotes would get to the inner shell and then `"` (not `'`) in the input would be dangerous, along with `$var`, `$(code)` and such! And if we left `\1` or `\2` unquoted in the context of the inner shell then it would be even worse.

In general one should pass arbitrary data to a shell as command line arguments, not in a command string. E.g. with `find -exec` [one can do this right](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/156010/108618). Code injection is then impossible, unless the actual (static) shell command executes a positional parameter or mishandles something badly. Unfortunately while invoking a shell from GNU `sed` all you can pass is a command string.